# Get the InsertId with Prepared Statements AND Stored Procedures?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I had some Prepared Statements working in PHP using mysqli. The requirements changed and now I'm supposed to move them to the DB, as Stored Procedures. This worked fine for most of the PSs, except for a couple that read the insertId for some further processing.
Ex:

```
$idAsdf = $stmtAsdf->insert_id;
```

where the PS performs an INSERT operation.
I've tried using an OUT parameter on the procedure which works fine on PHPMyAdmin, but can't connect it with the PHP server code outside the DB. I haven't found any example of this combination of elements being done. How can I get this insertId using both SPs and PSs?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For PDO Prepared Statement you can use PDO::lastInsertId  -http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

```
<?php 
try { 
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'username', 'password'); 

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO test (name, email) VALUES(?,?)"); 

try { 
    $dbh->beginTransaction(); 
    $tmt->execute( array('user', 'user@example.com')); 
    print $dbh->lastInsertId();
    $dbh->commit(); 
} catch(PDOExecption $e) { 
    $dbh->rollback(); 
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>"; 
} 
} catch( PDOExecption $e ) { 
print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>"; 
} 
?>
```

Just remember when using transaction return lastInsertId or store lastInsertId before commit.

For Stored Procedure - use LAST_INSERT_ID();

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test (name, email) VALUES ('value1', 'value2');
  SET out_param = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

**EDIT 1 :**

If you using MySQLi - then use mysqli_insert_id - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);

// set parameters and execute
$firstname = "John";
$lastname = "Doe";
$email = "john@example.com";
$stmt->execute();

printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $stmt->insert_id);

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

If facing problem with out_param, use select to return last insert id as result.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE last_id INT DEFAULT 0;
  INSERT INTO test (name, email) VALUES ('value1', 'value2');
  SET last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  SELECT last_id;
END
```

**EDIT 2 :**

If you are facing problem in retrieving Stored Procedure result set use following code -

```
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
           $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}
```

To access the out param use follwing code -

```
// execute the stored Procedure
// @uid - IN param, @userCount - OUT param
$result = $connect->query('call IsUserPresent(@uid, @userCount)');

// getting the value of the OUT parameter
$r = $connect->query('SELECT @userCount as userCount');
$row = $r->fetch_assoc();               

$toRet = ($row['userCount'] != 0);
```

Comment: Edited the answer. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. What I did was partially what you suggested (using "$result" and "$r", but with a more direct approach to get the values. Like:

`$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("CALL asd1(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt1 ->bind_param("siiii", $a, $s, $d, $f, $g);
 $stmt1 ->execute();
 $stmt1 ->close();
 $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
 $stmt2 ->execute();
 $stmt2 ->bind_result($qwe);
 $stmt2 ->fetch();
 $stmt2 ->close();`

Comment: @DarkKnight : I'm using MySQLi - from all the dozens entries I went through, you are the only one that made sense. Thank you Very Much!

Answer (score 0):

[`insert_id` is a property of **mysqli** class](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php), while you are trying to get it from a statement object.

Answer (score -1):

inside SP you can set like this `outParam = LAST_INSERT_ID();`
`LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the most recently generated ID is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis.

Comment: _**I've tried using an OUT parameter on the procedure which works fine on PHPMyAdmin, but can't connect it with the PHP server code outside the DB.**_

The problem is not with finding the insertId, but reading it from the PHP code. I already tried with both your method and with a `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` , but the PHP doesn't recognise it.